# acts as taggable on count across multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I am trying to find the total number of tag counts across multiple models.

In one model, it works great:

```
Post.tag_counts_on(:hashtags).order('count desc')
```

However, I had another model as well called Organization that also takes hashtags. That leaves me with 2 separate counts:

```
Post.tag_counts_on(:hashtags).order('count desc')
Organization.tag_counts_on(:hashtags).order('count desc')
```

However, I want to be able to get the total counts across the two. When I try to add them, they don't merge, but instead just stack the tables on one another:

```
Post.tag_counts_on(:hashtags).order('count desc') +
Organization.tag_counts_on(:hashtags).order('count desc')
```

There should be a method for all the associated models that allows the equivalent of something like:

```
Hashtag.tag_counts.order('count desc')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can go with a custom select

```
SELECT tags.name, count(*) as tag_count 
FROM tags JOIN taggings on taggings.tag_id = tags.id 
where taggings.taggable_type = 'Post' or taggings.taggable_type='Organization' 
GROUP BY tags.name 
ORDER BY tag_count DESC
```

use arel to build this query if needed